# Date-time picker formatting for Database input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to convert a jquery datetime picker in to a db input. But

`"10/24/2013 12:00 am +0300".to_datetime.utc.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")`

Give me an error;

`ArgumentError: invalid date`

How can i get it to work.

`"10/24/2013 12:00 am +0300"` is just an example of the input not just one specific input am working with.

I wish for something that can work better than this
`schedule = params[:message][:schedule].to_dateime.utc.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")`

Thank you everyone, i hope this works;

```
schedule = params[:message][:schedule]
scheduled_time = DateTime.strptime("#{schedule}","%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p %z").to_datetime.utc.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: When you say that it's just an example of the input, are you saying that the date format can change? If you don't know the format then you can't guarantee correct parsing.

Comment: @joonty you are correct for random format we can not use any methods predefined method.

Comment: @joonty its a form input.`<%= f.input :schedule, input_html: {id: 'schedule'} %>` format is consistent.

Comment: @acacia if the format is consistent then why doesn't the answer work?

Comment: No need for the `to_datetime` - it's already a datetime. And no need to interpolate `schedule` - just use `DateTime.striptime(schedule, ...)`. Also, why hope that it works? Why not try it?

Comment: @joonty, Very good idea ..works too!!

Comment: Good :) how about selecting it as the answer since it helped you out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `strptime` to specify the format of the string for parsing:

```
DateTime.strptime "10/24/2013 12:00 am +0300", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p %z"
```

Comment: @acacia please check my comment!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
Time.new("10/24/2013 12:00 am +0300").utc.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: The time parsing fails in this case (ruby 1.9.3-p392)

Answer (score 0):

Try following

You need to understand in which format you are getting your date-time
In given example it is in the format `"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p %z"`

Ref [`this`](http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime) for its meaning

```
DateTime.strptime("10/24/2013 12:00 am +0300", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p %z").to_datetime.utc.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```